# htaccess - how to force HTTPS on just my main domain, not on sub-domains

Tags: .htaccess

I've just added the following rule to force HTTPS on my payment page, simply because I'm not sure how to force HTTPS on just `domain.com` and not `user1.domain.com` - not quite sure how to do this or even if it's possible.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /join/payment
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

So I added that rule and it's working fine, however, is it possible to just force HTTPS on my full domain and not any of my sub-domains?

**My full htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|profile_pictures|fonts|stylesheets|robots\.txt)

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /join/payment
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^((www\.)?)domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/site/%1$1 [L,NC,P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!site/).*)$ http://domain.com/site/$1?host=%{HTTP_HOST}&page=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,P]
```

**Questions**

Is it possible to just force HTTPS on `domain.com` and not on subdomains? If it's possible to force HTTP instead of HTTPS on subdomains, I'd love to hear how to do that too.

Comment: Simply add another `RewriteCond` checking the host name before redirecting to HTTPS – similar to what you already have further down for redirecting to `domain.com` only. (Btw., the latter will redirect any subdomain that is not `www` to the base domain anyway, so you can’t really have that many other subdomains actually?)

Comment: All the sub-domains are dynamic so there's over 100 of them. It seems when I force HTTPS on just my domain, it unmasks the sub-domains.

Comment: Can you explain what last 2 rules are doing with `P` flag

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /join/payment
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^((www\.)?)domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

That is, add a condition to check that the HTTP_HOST is `www.domain.com` or `domain.com` before adding `https://` in front of it.

Comment: That kind of works, although when I type in say 'www.user1customdomain.com' that is masked, as the HOST is effectively my domain, it adds HTTPS and then shows "The identity of this website has not been verified." Is there anyway around this? In addition to this, if I visit "mydomain.com" it doesn't add the HTTPS because there's no www. (which is what I've removed).

Comment: The solution should work with our without `www.`, which is optional in the regex used for the rewrite condition. `Www.user1customdomain.com` is a completely different domain and should not match the regex at all, thus skipping the rewrite.